# Use Method, defined in a class, in drag event from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, class, reference

Hello i have a problem with my references.
For example:

```
    class Inset{

        constructor(){
            this.x = 1;
            this.y = 2;
            this.divBox = $('<div></div>);
            this.divBox.draggable({drag: function(event, ui){
                //Here i want to call the add funciton with my x and y but i dont get it, how i can reference to the add function.
            }})
        }

        add(x, y){
            return x+y;
        }
    }
```

How can i call the function add(x,y) from my Inset class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

JS

```
class Inset {
  constructor(){
    this.x = 1;
    this.y = 2;
    this.divBox = $('.draggable');
    this.divBox.draggable({ 
      drag: (event, ui) => {
        this.add(10,20);
      }
    });
  }

  add(x, y){
    console.log(x, y);
    return x + y;
  }
} 

new Inset();
```

CSS

```
.draggable {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="draggable"></div>
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/kieran/pen/EpbmYo)

Comment: glad I could help 

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new instance of the object upon which you can call the add function.

```
 new Inset().add(1, 2);//outputs 3
```

Comment: this is the reference from the draggable Object.